# Is it possible to somehow return a value parameter in a POST request using Magento2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to return value from magento2 when creating an attribute option, 
I make such a request with method POST

```
    {
  "option": 
        {
              "label": "Pavel",
              "value": "option_x",
              "sort_order": 0,
              "is_default": true


        }
}
```

The response value comes from the value of my request, that is, option_x, can I somehow set the id value that will be returned from the created option ?
I want the id created option from magento to be returned to me

Comment: Can you please describe your requirement in detail. what you are looking?

Comment: When I create an attribute, I want to return the value of the created attribute from magento, that is, its value in magento2, to write it to the database without making 2 requests for receiving and publishing